# Issue with a program Error: incompatible

Tags: c++, c, computer-science

First of all I am doing a program kinda simple long program, here is the full details:

> The P-v-T relation for real gases can take many forms. The simplest
>   relations are the ideal gas equation and the Van der Waals equation.
>   These relations are to be applied to superheated steam. The file
>   “pvt.txt” contains the P-v-T data of superheated steam (10 – 800 kPa)
>   for the temperature range of 200 oC through 1200 oC, obtained from the
>   steam tables.
>
> Write a C program to read the steam table data “pvt.txt”. In the C
>   program, estimate the density of steam for the pressure range 10
>   through 800 kPa, and temperature range 200 oC through 1200 oC,
>
> (1) Using the ideal-gas relation:
>        m3/kg where R = 0.4615 kJ/kgK, T is temperature [K] and P  is pressure [kPa].
>
> (2) Using the Van der Waals equation:
>
> where R = 0.4615 kJ/kgK, T is temperature [K] and P  is pressure
>   [kPa]. The constants are obtained from
>       and    where  Pcr = 22060  kPa and Tcr = 647.1 K.
>
> In each case, calculate the resulting percentage error of the
>   estimated density as follows: Error =   x 100% Submit a report which
>   must include:
>   1. Introduction,  algorithm or flowchart, the C program, and the density from steam table.
>   2. The estimated density table when using the ideal gas equation.
>   3. The percentage error table when using the ideal gas equation.
>   4. The estimated density table when using the Van der Waals equation.
>   5. The percentage error table when using the Van der Waals equation.
>   6. Discussion and conclusion. Note:  Density is the inverse of specific volume,
>
> pvt.txt:
>   [pvt txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjBht.png)

The first step of program already finished it but i am having problem with the second one ( using the van der waals equation ) here is what i have wrote

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
main(){
    FILE *f1;
    FILE *f2;

    f1 = fopen("pvt.txt","r");
    f2 = fopen("second.txt","w");

     int i,j;
     float v[9][6],vdr[9][6],edr[9][6]; //V
     float p[9]={10,50,100,200,300,400,500,600,800}; //Pressure
     float T[6]={200,400,600,800,1000,1200}; //Temperature
     float a,b,Pcr=22060,Tcr=647.1,R=0.4615,v0,diff;


    a=(27*pow(R,2)*pow(Tcr,2))/(64*Pcr);
    b=(R*Tcr)/(8*Pcr);


    //                  //

    /*Read input file for v from steam table*/
     for(i=0;i<=8;i=i+1)
       fscanf(f1,"%f %f %f %f %f %f",&v[i][0],&v[i][1],
            &v[i][2],&v[i][3],&v[i][4],&v[i][5]);

    /*Write v steam table to output file*/
    fprintf(f2, "The V Steam Values = \n");
     for(i=0;i<=8;i=i+1)
       fprintf(f2,"%f %f %f %f %f %f \n",v[i][0],v[i][1],
            v[i][2],v[i][3],v[i][4],v[i][5]);

            //          //
            while(diff>0.001)
                {
                     for(i=0;i<=8;i=i+1)
                        for(j=0;j<=5;++j)
                            v0=v;
                            v=b+ 0.4615*(T+273.15)/(p+a/(v0*v0));
                            diff=fabs(v-v0)/v0;
       }
/*Write v using VDR to output file*/
        fprintf(f2, "The V using VDR Values = \n");
     for(i=0;i<=8;i=i+1)
       fprintf(f2,"%f %f %f %f %f %f \n",v[i][0],v[i][1],
            v[i][2],v[i][3],v[i][4],v[i][5]);

}
```

Everytime its saying Error incompatible types when assigning to type 'float' from type 'float (*)[6]'| at these lines:

```
while(diff>0.001)
                    {
                         for(i=0;i<=8;i=i+1)
                            for(j=0;j<=5;++j)
                                v0=v;
                                v=b+ 0.4615*(T+273.15)/(p+a/(v0*v0));
                                diff=fabs(v-v0)/v0;
           }
```

What should i do to fix it?

Also here is a program hint provided:

```
/*Solving van der waals equation using trial-and-error
  p : kPa, t : Celcius, v : m^3/kg  */

#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
     float a,b,diff,v,vo,p,t;

     a=27*0.4615*0.4615*647.1*647.1/(64*22060.0);
     b=0.4615*647.1/(8*22060.0);

/*some test values*/

     p=10;
     t=200;

/*guess a value for v, Let vo=v and calculate a new
  v. If relative difference (diff) is greater than
  some tolerance, start new calculations */

     diff=100;
     v=10.0;
     while(diff>0.001)
       {vo=v;
        v= b+ 0.4615*(t+273.15)/(p+a/(vo*vo));
        diff=fabs(v-vo)/vo;
       }

     printf("%f\n",v);

     system("pause");
}
```

Comment: `v` is an array, `v0` is not. Which `v` are you trying to assign to `v0`?

Comment: Hint: `v` is not a `float`. Name your variables better to make this clearer.

Comment: Aside: I suggest you use `double` instead of `float` unless there is a very good reason why `double` should not be used. Your function definition `main()` suggests you are using out of date reference material.

Comment: Moreover you are using magic numbers which should be the same number: the array dimension size is `9` but your loops use `<= 8`. At the least, you should `#define` a value and change the loop condition to `<`. Similarly with `6` and `5`.

Comment: It's helpful to those answering if you can pinpoint exactly where your issue is and provide only the relevant details.

Comment: It could be so simple as this: `v0 = v[i][j]`, but it's only a guess.

Comment: Well I converted v0 to i and j but new error appeared and saying :error: assignment to expression with array type| and i already changed float to double tho

Comment: What is finally the question?  Are you asking something? did you get an error? Which was the error you got? did the program compile? did it run? did it generate any output? Did the compiler give the error? which was exactly the compiler error message?